# Python - DEAP & SCOOP: different result / Hall of Fame for each node?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, genetic-algorithm, deap

I'm using

- Python 3.6.4 / Anaconda custom (64-bit) [GCC 7.2.0] on linux
- SCOOP 0.7.2.0
- DEAP 1.2.2

to run the genetic algorithm example scoop/examples/deap_ga_onemax.py from https://github.com/soravux/scoop/blob/master/examples/deap_ga_onemax.py

on a HPC cluster using a SLURM script, see code posted below.

Please note, that line number 71 in deap_ga_onemax.py has been commented: `#random.seed(64)`

Python code:

```
"""
Code from the deap framework, available at:
https://code.google.com/p/deap/source/browse/examples/ga/onemax_short.py
Conversion to its parallel form took two lines:
from scoop import futures
toolbox.register("map", futures.map)
"""
import array
import random

import numpy

from deap import algorithms
from deap import base
from deap import creator
from deap import tools
from scoop import futures

creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", array.array, typecode='b',                 
fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()

# Attribute generator
toolbox.register("attr_bool", random.randint, 0, 100)

# Structure initializers
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual,     
toolbox.attr_bool, 100)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

def evalOneMax(individual):
    return sum(individual),

toolbox.register("evaluate", evalOneMax)
toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxTwoPoint)
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutFlipBit, indpb=0.05)
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=3)
toolbox.register("map", futures.map)

def main():
    #random.seed(64)

    pop = toolbox.population(n=100)
    hof = tools.HallOfFame(1)
    stats = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    stats.register("avg", numpy.mean)
    stats.register("std", numpy.std)
    stats.register("min", numpy.min)
    stats.register("max", numpy.max)

    pop, log = algorithms.eaSimple(pop, toolbox, cxpb=0.5, mutpb=0.2, ngen=10,stats=stats, halloffame=hof, verbose=True)

        return pop, log, hof

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pop, log, hof = main()
    print(hof)
```

SLURM script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -J xxx
#SBATCH -A xxx
#SBATCH -N 4
#SBATCH -n 4
#SBATCH --time=00:03:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1024M

#echo "ERROR"
hosts=$(srun bash -c hostname)
srun /projects/p_thermo_dat/software/python36/bin/python -m scoop --host $hosts -v scoop_deap_test.py > $(date +"%Y%m%d_%I%M%p")_log_scoop_deap_test.txt

exit
```

**Problem:**
Running deap_ga_onemax.py in parallel on 4 nodes with 4 processors each results in 4 different hall of fames. Running on 3 nodes results in 3 different hall of fames and so on. This way, each node has its own hall of fame.

How can I obtain one hall of fame containing the results from all nodes?

Any insight would be very helpful...

Answer (score -1):

The OP has also stated this question on DEAP's github issues. As a DEAP developper, I think it is more suited there and here is a link to the conversation.

https://github.com/DEAP/deap/issues/285